# Error while starting dispatch.fcgi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastcgi

I got this while trying to execute dispatch.fcgi in a dreamhost shared server
I dont know how to figure out a solution. How can i find the exact line that causes my this error?

```
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1084 - no such file to load -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/config_file.rb:50 - no such file to load -- Win32API
/home/pedmac1/apris.com.br/config/application.rb:7: warning: `*' interpreted as argument prefix
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31 - no such file to load -- bundler/setup
Exception `NoMethodError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rational.rb:78 - undefined method `gcd' for Rational(1, 2):Rational
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:243 - File exists - /home/pedmac1/.gems:
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31 - no such file to load -- set
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:38 - no such file to load -- set
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:38 - no such file to load -- set
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:38 - no such file to load -- set
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:38 - no such file to load -- set
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- set (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:1
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:151:in `resolve'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:90:in `specs'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:135:in `specs_for'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:124:in `requested_specs'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/environment.rb:23:in `requested_specs'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:11:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler.rb:100:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/setup.rb:6
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /home/pedmac1/apris.com.br/config/boot.rb:6
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /home/pedmac1/apris.com.br/config/application.rb:1
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from ./../config/environment.rb:2
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from dispatch.fcgi:15
```